# bitsadmin versionless download

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, 7-zip, url

I want to download the latest version of 7z.

My script downloads the current version, where in an edition I provide the necessary link and file name:

```
TITLE 7-ZIP
Reg.exe Query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" | find /i "x86" > NUL && set OS=32BIT || set OS=64BIT

:Download.
if %OS%==32BIT bitsadmin /Transfer 7-ZIPx86 /DOWNLOAD /Priority FOREGROUND https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1900.exe %temp%\7z1900.exe
if %OS%==64BIT bitsadmin /Transfer 7-ZIPx64 /DOWNLOAD /Priority FOREGROUND https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1900-x64.exe %temp%\7z1900-x64.exe

:Silent İnstall.
if %OS%==32BIT START /wait %temp%\7z1900.exe /S
if %OS%==64BIT START /wait %temp%\7z1900-x64.exe /S

:Temp Temizle.
if %OS%==32BIT DEL /F %temp%\7z1900.exe
if %OS%==64BIT DEL /F %temp%\7z1900-x64.exe

:Right click group ve CRC SHA remove.
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\7-Zip\Options" /v "MenuIcons" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\7-Zip\Options" /v "ContextMenu" /t REG_DWORD /d "16247" /f

:END
TIMEOUT /T 5
```

How to always download the latest version without the previous edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - Getting the current version of **[7-zip](/questions/tagged/7-zip)** is possible by downloading the file `history.txt` from `7-zip.org` and extracting the current version from it to create a direct link for use with `Bitsadmin`:

1. Download the `history.txt` file from `https://www.7-zip.org/history.txt`, this is a permanent `URL`/`link`, so use it...

```batch-file
"%__APPDIR__%bitsadmin.exe" /rawreturn /transfer 7-Zip-History "https://www.7-zip.org/history.txt" "%temp%\history.txt"
```

[image]

2. Use the `for` loop to get the current version in a variable from the`history.txt` file; using filters, your string will be the first match:

```batch-file
19.00
```

3. Use the last action to concatenate the file name with the download `7z link`, removing the period (19`.`00) in the string to set file name for `!_7z_x32!` and `!_7z_x64!` variables:

```batch-file
set "_7z_x32=7z%%~i" & set "_7z_x64=7z%%~i-x64"
```

4. Now we can set the download link variable with the current/latest version of the 7-Zip file by concatenating the name and downloading the file `!_URL!` 7-Zip using sub-string in the variable `!_url!` replacing `.` with nothing (removing/not showing) and adding `.exe`/`-x64.exe` at the end of the link/`!_URL!`:

```batch-file
rem :: if "!_os!" == "x32" the link URL will be set "_URL=https://www.7-zip.org/a/!_7z_x32:.=!.exe!"
rem :: if "!_os!" == "x64" the link URL will be set "_URL=https://www.7-zip.org/a/!_7z_x64:.=!-x64.exe!"

set "_URL=https://www.7-zip.org/a/!_7z_%_os%:.=!.exe"
```

---

```batch-file
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

set "_key=HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" & title <nul & color 0A & "%__APPDIR__%mode.com" 77,8
title 7-Zip Download/Install & "%__APPDIR__%Reg.exe" Query "!_key!"|find/i "x86">nul && set "_os=x64"||set "_os=x32"

"%__APPDIR__%bitsadmin.exe" /rawreturn /transfer 7-Zip-History "https://www.7-zip.org/history.txt" "%temp%\history.txt" && for /f %%i in ('
type "%temp%\history.txt"^|"%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe" /b .[0-9\.0-9].^|"%__APPDIR__%findstr.exe" /vi "Alpha  Beta"')do set "_7z_v=%%i" && (
set "_7z_x32=7z%%~i" && set "_7z_x64=7z%%~i-x64" && set "_URL=https://www.7-zip.org/a/!_7z_%_os%:.=!.exe" && goto :Download:) || goto :EOF

:Download:
"%__APPDIR__%bitsadmin.exe" /NoWrap /Transfer "7-Zip v!_7z_v! !_os!Bit" /Download /Priority Foreground "!_URL!" "%tmp%\!_7z_%_os%:.=!.exe"

:Silent Install:
start "7-Zip v.!_7z_v! !_os!Bit" /wait "%tmp%\!_7z_%_os%:.=!.exe" /S

:Temp Temizle:
2>&1>nul del /q /F "%tmp%\!_7z_%_os%:.=!.exe" "%tmp%\history.txt"

:Right click group ve CRC SHA remove:
for %%i in ("MenuIcons 1","ContextMenu 16247")do for /f tokens^=1-2 %%I in ('echo/%%~i
')do "%__APPDIR__%Reg.exe" add "HKCU\Software\7-Zip\Options" /v "%%I" /t REG_DWORD /d "%%J" /f

:END:
"%__APPDIR__%TIMEOUT.exe" 5 & endlocal & goto :EOF
```

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[For Loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)**

  [√] **[Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√] **[CMD/Bat String Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)**

  [√] **[Conditional Execution || && ...](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)**

Answer (score 1):

bitsadmin troubles are happening in big files.
Simple I did with aria2.

```
@ECHO OFF
TITLE aria2
===============================================================================================================================================================================================
REG.EXE QUERY "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" | find /i "x86" > NUL && SET OS=32BIT || SET OS=64BIT
IF NOT EXIST "%TEMP%\aria2c.exe" IF %OS%==32BIT POWERSHELL -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://www.dropbox.com/s/l0k5gvygl53pzkg/aria2c.exe?dl=1', '%TEMP%\aria2c.exe')"
IF NOT EXIST "%TEMP%\aria2c.exe" IF %OS%==64BIT POWERSHELL -Command "(New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://www.dropbox.com/s/vh6lew82qm4ud9i/aria2c.exe?dl=1', '%TEMP%\aria2c.exe')"
===============================================================================================================================================================================================
TITLE 7-Zip
@ECHO ON
:: İndir
IF %OS%==32BIT %TEMP%\aria2c.exe -x16 -s16 -k1M -d%TEMP% --auto-file-renaming=false "https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1900.exe" -o 7z.exe
IF %OS%==64BIT %TEMP%\aria2c.exe -x16 -s16 -k1M -d%TEMP% --auto-file-renaming=false "https://www.7-zip.org/a/7z1900-x64.exe" -o 7z.exe
:: Kur
START /wait %TEMP%\7z.exe /S
:: Sağtık gruplansın ve CRC SHA kaldır
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\7-Zip\Options" /v "MenuIcons" /t REG_DWORD /d "1" /f
Reg.exe add "HKCU\Software\7-Zip\Options" /v "ContextMenu" /t REG_DWORD /d "16247" /f
:: Kapat
TIMEOUT /T 5
EXIT
```